# Confused about merchantEmail and payerEmail on PayPal Invoicing API

Tags: paypal

Below is an example of payload to send to PayPal API to create payment to another merchant behalf. *The example is taken from PayPal documentation page*

```
# ** Payload **
{
"requestEnvelope":
{
"errorLanguage":"en_US"    # Language of returned errors
},
"invoice":
{
"merchantEmail":"receiver@example.com",  # Receiver/Merchant e-ddress
"payerEmail":"sender@example.com",       # Sender/Buyer e-dress
"currencyCode":"USD",
"paymentTerms":"DueOnReceipt",
"itemList":
{
"item":[{
"name":"BananaPlant",
"quantity":"1",
"unitPrice":"38.95"
},
{
"name":"PeachTree",
"quantity":"2",
"unitPrice":"14.95"
}]
}
}
}
```

I am confused about the field `merchantEmail` and `payerEmail`. Which is what? Is the merchant email my email or for the party I am creating invoice for? in the comment `#Receiver/Merchant e-address` made me more confused. Is it for the email who will be *receive* and pay the invoice?

**For the sake of conversion. Lets use following example for answers:**

1. `api_user@domain.com` is the user who calling the api to create invoice for merchants behalf.
2. `merchant@domain.com` is the user whom behalf `api_user@domain.com` creating Invoices.
3. `user@domain.com` is the user who is being charged.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Merchant email should be the store owners email. If you are using paypal sandbox developer account, You can use your email id for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To Clarify for You

`merchantEmail` is the email of the account that will be receiving the invoice *aka seller*.

`payerEmail` is the email of the account that is sending payment/buying the good. 
The `api_user@domain.com` is the account specifying the API Credential set. Usually referred to as the *API Username*.